# How to install the locate command?

Tags: command-line, locate

I wish to have the command `locate` in ubuntu 12.04 (which is used for finding files. I believe there is such a command but I cannot see it in ubuntu 12.04  Is it part of any package?

Comment: Try using this command: `sudo apt-get install locate`.

Comment: For the future: if you're looking for a program and don't know the package, install apt-file: `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and search for the program using apt-file: `apt-file search /usr/bin/locate`.

Comment: In a standard Ubuntu install this often isn't needed - if you type a command on the command-line that Ubuntu doesn't know, it'll often suggest which package to install to get that command.  Come to mention it, I think `locate` is already installed in a standard Ubuntu install anyway, so maybe this doesn't help.

Comment: this is actually an unfortunately perpetually useful question (and not at all a "just install it" question), as this particular utility keeps changing names for whatever reason (and has cross-platform variations). There's `locate` that keeps dis-/re-appearing, and `plocate`, which (arguably) might be an improved (or the same as) `locate`, and there's `mlocate` which might be its own thing or just a dummy package for`plocate` or `locate` but now seems to be gone, and wasn't there iir a `slocate` at some point? aaaack

Answer (score 129):

`sudo apt-get install mlocate` should install the 'locate' command.

---

`mlocate` maintains a database of all your files and is re-indexed once a day by default.  If you want it to re-index immediately then run `sudo updatedb` from the command line.

If you get a `cannot stat` error when you run `locate`, then you need to run `sudo updatedb` to populate the database, just as if you wanted to re-index immediately.

---

From Ubuntu 22.04 onwards, [`mlocate` is a transitional dummy package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mlocate) that installs `plocate`, so you can run `sudo apt-get install plocate` instead to install `plocate` directly.

Comment: I believe that the mlocate package installs a mlocate job in /etc/cron.daily which runs updatedb daily.

Comment: Just after you do that, if you try to call locate, you will get the following error: "locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory". To solve that, please refer to @enxotib response in: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26188/how-do-i-enable-locate-and-queue-the-database-to-be-built

Comment: You probably want to run `sudo updatedb` after installing **mlocate**, since the search database needs to be optimized for first time use.

Comment: If you're on CentOS/RHEL/Amazon Linux, use `sudo yum install mlocate` to install it. Also the same, run `sudo updatedb` to initialize the database for the first time.

Comment: **Warning**: At least on pop_os! 22.04 `mlocate` is a transitional dummy package to [`plocate`](https://plocate.sesse.net/), which have some advantages but have fewer features ([like `--transliterate`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104990/349837))

Comment: note that PopOS is not Ubuntu, and this is a 10 year old post.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install plocate
```

Use this to install `locate` command in 22.04

`plocate` is  [better](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/09/plocate-is-much-faster-locate-drop-in.html) than `mlocate`

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, I'm doing this install right now. Why is it better, links to some source? [It helps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to provide some context when you say "better" that sounds subjective.

Comment: I have added the link