# Search with diacritics / accents characters with `locate` command

Tags: command-line, search, find, locate

Sometimes I need to search files with accented characters (diacritic in general), usually with locate (mlocate flavor, *Merging Locate*; see below the warning related to plocate). I wish to setup (maybe in `/etc/updatedb.conf`) so it let me search for this special characters using a certain language mapping, for example:

```
a == âàáäÂÀÂÄ
e == êèéëÊÈÉË
i == îïíÎÏ
o == ôöóÔÖ
u == ûùüÛÜÙ
c == çÇ
n == ñ
```

So `locate -i liberación` also should search for file names with string *liberacion* and even *liberaciòn*.

### Notes and assumptions

- And maybe others: *ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆ ÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏ ÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞ ßàáâãäåæç èéêëìíîïðñòóôõö øùúûüýþÿ*.
- This is a common situation on [romance languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages) like Spanish, French, and German.
- I'm always using a locale 100% UTF-8.
- I would rather not have to use regular expressions.
- A patch might use ASCII transliterations of Unicode as [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/)/[cUnidecode](https://github.com/logston/cunidecode) does. Most of mlocate is written on C.

### Related

- [Similar question but using `find`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839486/find-files-with-accented-characters-unix)
- Miloslav Trmač (`mlocate` developer) [say here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1468131#c1) that the official [source code is on pagure.io](https://pagure.io/mlocate) (and [a fork on Github](https://github.com/msekletar/mlocate)).
- I file [an issue on mlocate repo at Pagure.io](https://pagure.io/mlocate/issue/40) to add this feature.

  - **Update 2018-02**: This can be fixed with [this pull request](https://pagure.io/mlocate/pull-request/41) by [marcotrevisan](https://pagure.io/user/marcotrevisan). Will add a `-t`/`--transliterate` support using `iconv` to match accented.
  - **Update 2018-03**: `mlocate` with support for `--transliterate` is now included in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver ([v2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlocate/0.26-2ubuntu2) and [v3.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mlocate/0.26-2ubuntu3.1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### mlocate

Now with **mlocate** 0.26 we have `-t --transliterate` option (see [the man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/mlocate.1.html)) on Ubuntu 18.04+ (without the need of workarounds):

Creating some test files:

```
$ touch liberación liberacion liberaciôn
```

Update and search:

```
$ updatedb
$ locate --transliterate liberacion 
/home/pablo/liberacion
/home/pablo/liberación
/home/pablo/liberaciôn
```

So **now `locate -t liberación` also search for files with string `liberacion` and even `liberaciòn`**!

Finally, creating an alias... :-)

```sh
$ alias locate="locate --transliterate"
```

### plocate

[plocate](https://plocate.sesse.net/): is a *much faster locate* with *smaller index*. **But doesn't have a `--transliterate` option**, and won't have anytime soon, as said from its only maintainer (Steinar Gunderson):

> This is highly nontrivial, unfortunately. mlocate can get away with it because it scans through each and every filename linearly; plocate doesn't, which is why it is so much faster than mlocate, but also makes such locale-dependent searches much harder. So no, this is unlikely to happen anytime soon, unfortunately.

I couldn't find an issue tracker related to this project.

However it has `--regex`, so it seems internnally could use something simmilar to [Ravexina's aproach](https://askubuntu.com/a/909184/349837).

On distros with `plocate` by default I remove it, installed mlocate and hold it so isn't replaced with plocate:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
wget "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mlocate/mlocate_0.26-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb"
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt-mark hold mlocate
```

Answer (score 3):

If we take a look at `updatedb.conf(5)`, we'll find that there is no much we can do with configuration items.

So we are going to write a script using `locate`; At the end we are able to run something like `my-locate.sh liberacion` or `my-locate.sh liberâciòn` and it will brings us all the possible combinations.

---

#### Lets start

First create a simple file as our database anywhere you want it to be, e.g: `~/.mydb`; then add your accents characters into that file like this:

```
aâàáäÂÀÂÄ
eêèéëÊÈÉË
iîïíÎÏ
uûùüÛÜÙ
cçÇ
oôöóÔÖóòòò
...
...
```

Then we need a small script which does the job for us, I wrote a simple one:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Final search term 
STR=""

# Loop throughout all characters of desired string
for (( i=0; i<${#1}; i++ )); do

  # Split the string in one char
  CH="${1:$i:1}"

  # Find all possible combinations of this char
  CHARS=$(grep "$CH" ~/.mydb)

  # Add an "or" operator between characters
  REG=$(echo "$CHARS" |  sed 's/.\{1\}/&\|/g' )
  REG="($REG)"

  # Append all possible combination of this character
  # to our final search term as an or statement
  if [ "$REG" == '()' ];
  then
   STR=$STR$CH
  else
   STR=$STR$REG
  fi

done

# locate it using regex
locate --regex "$STR$"
```

Now save it somewhere in your PATH with a desired name, e.g: in `~/bin`. It should be already in your PATH environment.

After all simply use something like this to search all possible combinations.

```
my-locate.sh liberacion
```

Will find for me all of these:

```
~/lab/liberacion
~/lab/liberaciòn
~/lab/liberación
~/lab/liberâciòn
~/lab/liberäciòn
~/lab/libÈrâciòn
```

Comment: You can use `grep -f` or `fgrep` to avoid the interpretation of `"$CH"` as a special character, e. g. `grep ^` would match any line but `grep -f ^` only matches those that contain the character `^`. It may also be easier to use character classes to craft the regular expression, i. e. `REG="[$CHARS]"` is probably easier than your `sed` command. Watch out for special characters though! Otherwise a good approach. +1

Comment: This seems a good alternative if we have to use `plocate`, but for some reason I'm getting too many apparently false positives. Also, do you know if it's possible to avoid [SC2001](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2001) on line 18?