# Cannot locate file after moving

Tags: command-line, find, tar, mv

The thing is that I am starting after a few months of experience in linux to use the command line. I was trying to use a new "cursor theme". I found on reddit that I needed to move the file from the "Download" directory to `/usr/share/icons.`
Because it didn't work I figured it needed to be moved to the second option the reddit post stated: `~/.local/share/icons`  . I then figured that the reason why it didn't work was because it was a compressed file.
These are the commands that I put into the terminal.

```
~$ sudo mv /usr/share/icons/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors
~$ ls /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursorscursors  index.theme  posy-s-cursor.tar.gz
mv /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz ~/.local/share/icons
mv: cannot move '/usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz' to '/home/x/.local/share/icons': Permission denied
~$ sudo mv /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz ~/.local/share/icons
~$ sudo mv  ~/.local/share/icons/posy-s-cursor-tar.gz /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz
mv: cannot stat '/home/x/.local/share/icons/posy-s-cursor-tar.gz': Not a directory
```

I would appreciate if someone would please:

- locate the posy-s-cursor.tar.gz file and state me how to move it to `/usr/share/icons`
- tell me how to decompress a file using the command line.

Thanks a lot usrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your file, search in the two folders that you have been dealing with:

```
find /usr/share -name "posy-s-cursor.tar.gz"
find /home/x -name "posy-s-cursor.tar.gz"
```

See [linuxhint.com](https://linuxhint.com/use-the-find-command-in-linux-to-search-files/) or `man find` for more info on `find` command.

If not found, you may search other areas, but this could take pretty long. For much faster search over the whole disk, you can use locate (see [askubuntu page regarding installing locate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215503/how-to-install-the-locate-command)), but it is trickier to use as the database needs to be updated (with command `sudo updatedb`) in order to work properly with newly created/copied/moved files). Or just forget about the lost file and download it again.

Your last command

```
sudo mv  ~/.local/share/icons/posy-s-cursor-tar.gz /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz
```

would work for you, if:

- your file `posy-s-cursor-tar.gz` exists in `~/.local/share/icons/`
- full path `/usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/` already exists (including the directory `breeze_cursors`. If not, the missing directory needs to be created first with `mkdir`.

To extract the tar.gz into the current directory (supposing you are in the directory, where your tar.gz file is located):

```
tar -xvf posy-s-cursor.tar.gz
```

See [linuxhint.com](https://linuxhint.com/linux-tar-command/) or `man tar` for more info on `tar` command.

Comment: I have run the ''find'' command in the combinations that you have sent me. I don't get an error neither I get a result. I'm going to assume that the file is now lost in the depths of the computer. I will now redownload the file and decompress it using tar. Thanks a lot for the detailed response.

Comment: Maybe your file got renamed in addition to moving, because it is something that mv command also does. For example, with your command 'sudo mv /usr/share/icons/breeze_cursors/posy-s-cursor.tar.gz ~/.local/share/icons', if the directory icons did not existed in ~/.local/share/, your file got renamed to a file with the name 'icons' in directory ~/.local/share/.